# Refresh After Defaults Accessibility Write

Tags: macos, system-settings

I need to programmatically change the Accessibility "Reduce Transparency" System Setting under macOS Ventura.  The change is easy enough…

```
defaults write com.apple.Accessibility EnhancedBackgroundContrastEnabled -bool true
```

…but for the life of me, I can't persuade the interface to update after the write.  I've pkilled "AccessibilitySettingsExtension" and every other likely suspect, to no avail.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to turn on/off the Trackpad with the following but its not taking:

defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad USBMouseStopsTrackpad 1;
defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad USBMouseStopsTrackpad 1


killall Dock was another solution I tried

Comment: Alas, I did not.